# Substitution depending on the value of other column

Tags: bash, substitution

I want to perform a conditional substitution in several large text files. The structure is

```
1 ad sd bg we we A.2 890 3434 DATA
2 gf nh ok wa we A.1 890 3434 DATA
3 gf nh ok wa we A.1 890 3434 
...
...
```

I would like to do, when the value "DATA" exists in the 10th column (it does not always happen), check whether the element of the 7th column is A.1. In that case, substitute it for B.2

I tried mixed see plus awk approaches but could not get it done, any hints for doing this in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will locate the line that contain both "DATA" and "A.1" and replace "A.1" with "B.2" and give you the new output.

NOTE: The following commands do not differentiate between specific fields. As long as "DATA" and "A.1" are present in the same line "A.1" will be changed to "B.2".

```
sed -e '/A\.1.*DATA/!d;s/A\.1/B\.2/' /yourfile
```

To edit the file and keep the other lines in place you may want to try the following bash script. The following contains an inline edit. PRIOR TO TESTING ANYTHING PLEASE BACKUP YOUR FILE.

```
#!/bin/bash

ORIG=$(sed -e '/A\.1.*DATA/!d' /yourfile)
NEW=$(sed -e '/A\.1.*DATA/!d;s/A\.1/B\.2/' /yourfile)

sed -i "s/${ORIG}/${NEW}/g" /yourfile
```

NOTE: For OS X users you may want to try the following. The -i switch differs a bit on OS X. (The scripts does contain an inline edit so before testing please backup your file.)

```
#!/bin/bash

ORIG=$(sed -e '/A\.1.*DATA/!d' /yourfile)
NEW=$(sed -e '/A\.1.*DATA/!d;s/A\.1/B\.2/' /yourfile)

sed -i '' "s/${ORIG}/${NEW}/g" /yourfile
```

Comment: This is not intended to search and replace for the combination of A.1 and DATA more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$10=="DATA"&&$7=="A.1"{$7="B.1"}1'
```